# semantic ui checkbox is not changing knockout data-bind value

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, semantic-ui

Here's a checkbox question. I have a boolean Knockout observable that is defined in the viewModel function:

```
self.upNeededCB = ko.observable(false);
```

(and the `applyBindings`, of course)

With the Semantic UI classes in the html:

```html
<div class="ui toggle checkbox upCB">
    <label> Needed</label>
    <input  type="checkbox" data-bind="checked:upNeededCB"  >
</div>
```

But when I click the toggle, the UI changes, but it is not reflected in the Knockout observable, which I am examining using `alert(ko.toJSON(self));`.

What do I need to do to make the UI connect to the knockout data?

UPDATE: calling `$(.ui.checkbox).checkbox();` seemed to be the culprit, for some reason.

Comment: Consider posting this on jsfiddle or some similar site, to show us the problem.

Comment: Working fine: https://jsfiddle.net/n4Lh8ufw/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to switch up the order of the `input` and the `label`, then things will work fine:

```js
$(function() {
  var ViewModel = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.upNeededCB = ko.observable(false);
  }

  ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel);
});
```

```css
label { cursor: pointer; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.1.8/semantic.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.1.8/semantic.min.js"></script>

<div class="ui toggle checkbox upCB">
  <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked:upNeededCB">
  <label>Needed</label>
</div>

<hr> Debug info: <pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($root)"></pre>
```

Comment: Thank you. Good catch.  What was happening in this case (and I didn't disclose), was that calling `$('.ui.checkbox').checkbox();` afterward, causes the Knockout value to be disconnected ... for some reason.